# Box floats under menu instead of next to it

Tags: css

I got a menu to the left and a header up there. Then I got a black box to the right that is supposed to fill all of the remaining space to the right but the problem is that the black box  doesn't float next to the menu, it floats left UNDER the menu. I would appreciate if someone could help me out with this.

JS: http://jsfiddle.net/GrXLa/1/

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #ececec;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
 }
.header {
    min-height: 54px;
    background-color: #4d7496;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #2a4053;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 240px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    position: absolute;
    top: 58px;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}

.sidebar  .left_menu {
    width: 180px;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    color: #555555;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar  .left_menu:hover {
    width: 177px;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    border-right: 3px solid #668eb0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.header_menu {
    height: 14px;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-right: -1px;
    border-right: 1px solid #3d5c78;
    border-left: 1px solid #3d5c78;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #2a4053;
    float: right;
}

.header_menu:hover {
    background-color: #557a9a;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 20px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center
 }

    .content h2.title {
        font-size: 21px;
        color: #efefef;
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: -5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid
     }

.signin h2.title {
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #efefef;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid
 }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="header">
    <img src="theme/default/images/logo.png" style="padding: 10px;"/>
    <a href="logout.php"><div class="header_menu"><img src="theme/default/images/lock.png" style="margin-right: 10px;" /> Logout</div></a>
    <a href="edit_acc.php"><div class="header_menu"><img src="theme/default/images/user.png" style="margin-right: 10px;" />Edit Account</div></a>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
    <a href="index.php"><div class="left_menu"><img src="theme/default/images/home.png" style="margin-right: 10px;" />Dashboard</div></a>
    <a href="bank.php"><div class="left_menu"><img src="theme/default/images/coin.png" style="margin-right: 10px;" />Add Funds</div></a>
    <a href="bank.php?withdraw"><div class="left_menu"><img src="theme/default/images/withdraw.png" style="margin-right: 10px;" />Withdraw Funds</div></a>
    <a href="order.php"><div class="left_menu"><img src="theme/default/images/cart.png" style="margin-right: 10px;" />Place Order</div></a>
    <a href="orders.php"><div class="left_menu"><img src="theme/default/images/order.png" style="margin-right: 10px;" />My Order</div></a>
    <a href="change.php"><div class="left_menu"><img src="theme/default/images/star.png" style="margin-right: 10px;" />Change Membership</div></a>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <h2 class="title">Add Funds</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the content in the `.content` div?

Comment: Oh yes, the "black box" is the .content div that is supposed to fill the remaining space to the right and float next to the left menu instead of under it.

Comment: First I'd suggest simplify your HTML a bit.. you don't need all those div's inside your a tags.. second, your sidebar menu is position in 'absolute'.. that's a problem also

Answer (score 2):

Your problems are, that you

- position the menu absolute, which takes it out of the "normal flow"
- additionally set the content div to `width: 100%`
- float the content div

So the solution is to avoid all of the above and simply give the content element a left margin of the width of the menu (in your case 240px). That's it ...!

Here is your updated [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GrXLa/2/).

Comment: i did not even notice this absolute position, i only focused on float and layout

Comment: Perfect answer! Another option could also be:  .content{width:calc(100% - 285px);float:right}

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, if you want an element aside a floatting element to use all space left avalaible, it should not float, it will by defaut use all width avalaible as a `block` element does.

To keep aside and not wrap belo or lay under the floatting element, you need to trigger its layout.

`overflow:hidden;` , here in this case will do the job. .content will mind floatting element inside it and outside it. Do not give it any `width` or `height`, there is no need. eventually a `min-height` can be used. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GrXLa/1/)**

```
.content {
    overflow:hidden;
    min-height: 100%;/* this works if parent has an height set */
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center
 }
```

Inside `.content`, image can or should be set to `max-width:100%`.

---

Beside , the absolute positionning comes out of the flow and is therefor not seen by other element of the page. Keep side bar floatting in the flow.
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GrXLa/4/)**

```
.sidebar {
    width: 240px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    /* Useless without positionning
    top: 58px;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;*/
    border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1;    
    float: left;/* make it float in the flow*/
}

.sidebar  .left_menu {
    width: 180px;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    color: #555555;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```